# Redirect issue with subcategory path

Tags: redirect, redirect-url

I am just wondering why my subcategory path not redirect to cms page when i click on any cms page. When i click on cms page the subcategory path redirects to cms with parent category url.
please go through this site [click here](http://themaorishop.co.nz)

EX: www.example.com/category/subcategory... now click on about us page it will redirect to www.example.com/category/aboutus

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried by clearing cache and by doing reindexing?

Comment: What kind of extension are you using for the topmenu? This isn't default Magento

Comment: need to more details basically code

Comment: I don't have too much knowledge of code but what i found at the time of re-indexing is url.php throwing exception at protected $_saveRewritesHistory = ; when i removed the equal sign protected $_saveRewritesHistory; now it's working fine. @GirishSH Amit Bera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you use relative links in your html code eg.:

```
<li><a title="About Us" href="about-us">About Us</a></li>
```

You should change them to absolute ones by adding slash there:

```
<li><a title="About Us" href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
```

If it's done in template file, it will be even better to use site URL helper:

```
<li><a title="About Us" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('about-us')?>">About Us</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you provide me more details of how to use site URL helper. It looks good topic.

Comment: Kishor, it's part inside the <?php ?> tags.